# How to create and display a Funnel report and chart on leads?

Tags: reporting, leads, charts

Our marketing department are looking for a funnel report of our leads current status.

The information should look like any funnel report, but I don't see how I can collect the data.

The values need to be:

1. Total number of leads created this year.
2. Total number of leads that moved to the next stage (Contacted)
3. Total number of leads that moved to the next stage (Q processing)
4. Total number of Qualified leads (generally a small number)

The first value is easy to collect, but how can I display all 4 in one funnel report/chart?

A lot of the information I need is in the Lead History report

[image]

So while the "Field/Event" equals: "Lead Status" I can see the old and the new values.

There should be someway I can calculate these fields, and than display either in a funnel, or even a cumulative bar chart (not ideal)

Ideas?

Comment: Since much of the information from leads is essentially deleted upon conversion, it would seem that to get the data for #2, #3 & #4 you'd need to create an object similar to what's used for analytic snapshots to save lead historical data to when a leads is converted. Ditto if your org deletes leads for any reason.